# how to insert multiple array into database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need help. What seems to be the problem with our php codes? We can't seem to insert our data into our database. I'm just a beginner and I'm tasked to store multiple data into multiple arrays into our database. What we're actually doing is to enter a number (ex: 5) and 5 forms should show within that page. each form would consist of name address and tel phone number. after that we submit it to our database. We have already controlled hot many forms to show but we weren't able to store the data inserted. Can anyone help us please? Thank you.

form.php

```
<form method="POST" action="form.php">
<input type="text" name="waw" />
<input type="submit" />

<?php 
$i=0;

while ($i<$_POST['waw'])
{
?>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="input.php">
<!-- Person #1 -->

<input type="text" name="username[]" />

<input type="text" name="phonenum[]" />

<input type="text" name="add[]" />


<?php 
$i++;
}
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

input.php

```
<?php

$username="maizakath";
$password="12345";
$database="tryinsert";
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("<b>Unable to specified database</b>");



$sql_start = 'INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES '; 
$sql_array = array(); 
$queue_num = $_POST['waw']; 
foreach ($_POST['username'] as $row=>$name)
{
$username = $name;
$phonenum = $_POST['phonenum'][$row];
$add = $_POST['add'][$row];
$sql_array[] = '(' . $username . ', ' . $phonenum . ', ' . $add . ')'; 
if (count($sql_array) >= $queue_num)
{ 
mysql_query($sql_start . implode(', ', $sql_array)); 
$sql_array = array(); 
}
}
if (count($sql_array) > 0) 
{
mysql_query($sql_start . implode(', ', $sql_array))or die(mysql_error());
} 


?>
```

Comment: Would you please reformat your code so it's readable?  Take each line of code and prefix it with an additional four spaces so the site will render it as preformatted.  I don't have sufficient reputation to edit the post myself.  \c:

Comment: @Dathan: I reformatted the code.

Comment: done, thanks. beginner here. thank you

Comment: Is localhost defeined as const? If you haven't defined it ealier it seems to issue warning. If localhost is a name of the host you have to enclose it with quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've modified your code to make it work:

form.php

```
<form method="POST" action="form.php">
<input type="text" name="waw" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<form method="POST" action="input.php">
<?php 
$i=0;

while ($i<$_GET['waw'])
{
?>

<!-- Person #1 -->

<input type="text" name="username[]" />

<input type="text" name="phonenum[]" />

<input type="text" name="add[]" /><br />


<?php 
$i++;
}
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

input.php

```
<?php


$username="maizakath";
$password="12345";
$database="tryinsert";
mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("<b>Unable to specified database</b>");



$sql_start = 'INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES '; 
$sql_array = array(); 
$queue_num = $_POST['waw']; 
foreach ($_POST['username'] as $row=>$name)
{
$username = $name;
$phonenum = $_POST['phonenum'][$row];
$add = $_POST['add'][$row];
$sql_array[] = '("' . $username . '", "'.$phonenum.'", "'.$add.'")'; 
if (count($sql_array) >= $queue_num) {
  $query_single=$sql_start . implode(', ', $sql_array);
  mysql_query($query_single); 
  $sql_array = array(); 
}
}

if (count($sql_array) > 0)  {
  $query = $sql_start . implode(', ', $sql_array);
  mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
}

?>
```

It works fine. I've just tested it on my local machine.

**EDIT(Comments)**:

1. Usage of variable $queue_num in input.php is senseless, because this variable is available only in form.php script('wow' input placed in another form, which is submitted to file form.php, not input.php). So `if (count($sql_array) >= $queue_num)` block works wrong;
2. Check your config settings for the database connection(as I've wrote in comment, you have to define constant with name 'localhost' or enclose word localhost with quotes);
3. I've modified your form, because it had wrong structure;
4. I didn't understand the objective of creating first form in form.php.

You can modify this code to make it more appropriate for your case. But firsat of all try to use this one.

**Note.** Use [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function to see your $_POST array during debugging to understand, what variables are available.

Comment: Thank you so much. You were right. And thanks for explaining how some codes were not needed. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I Had tried its work fine but when inserting into database it will insert null value also if user did'nt filled up the whole field.

Answer (score 0):

I have stored two arrays in one table at the same time. Hope this will help you.

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($element_name as $element_names){
        $element_value = $_POST['element_value'];
        $element_names_insert = mysql_query("insert into wp_remote_fields
        set
            remote_fields = '".$element_names."',
            remote_values = '".$element_value[$i]."'
            ");     
        $i++;           
    }
?>
```