# php/pdo insert into database mssql with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, database, pdo

I need some help

Is there a way to make this in PDO? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899508/6208408
Yes I know I could change to mysql but I use a mssql server and can't use mysql. I tried some things but I'm not as good with PDO as mysql... It's hard to find some good examples of inserting array's into database with PDO. So quickly said I have a PDO based code connected to a mssql webserver.

best regards joep

I tried this before:

```
//id
$com_id = $_POST['com_id'];
//array

$mon_barcode = $_POST['mon_barcode'];                   
$mon_merk = $_POST['mon_merk'];
$mon_type = $_POST['mon_type'];
$mon_inch = $_POST['mon_inch'];
$mon_a_date = $_POST['mon_a_date'];
$mon_a_prijs = $_POST['mon_a_prijs'];

$data = array_merge($mon_barcode, $mon_merk, $mon_type, $mon_inch, $mon_a_date, $mon_a_prijs);
try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO IA_Monitor (Com_ID, Barcode, Merk, Type, Inch, Aanschaf_dat, Aanschaf_waarde) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $insertData = array();


    foreach($_POST['mon_barcode'] as $i => $barcode)                        
    {
        $insertData[] = $barcode;
    }

    if (!empty($insertData))
    {
        implode(', ', $insertData);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($insertData);

    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

Comment: @Cemal correct, I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should fix your problems.

```
$db_username='';
$db_password='';

$conn = new \PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost,1521;Database=testdb", $db_username, $db_password,[]);
//above added per @YourCommonSense's request to provide a complete example to a code fragment

if (isset($_POST['com_id'])) { //was com_id posted?
    //id
    $com_id = $_POST['com_id'];
    //array
    $mon_barcode = $_POST['mon_barcode'];
    $mon_merk = $_POST['mon_merk'];
    $mon_type = $_POST['mon_type'];
    $mon_inch = $_POST['mon_inch'];
    $mon_a_date = $_POST['mon_a_date'];
    $mon_a_prijs = $_POST['mon_a_prijs'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO IA_Monitor (Com_ID, Barcode, Merk, Type, Inch, Aanschaf_dat, Aanschaf_waarde) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($mon_barcode as $i => $barcode) {
            $stmt->execute([$com_id, $barcode, $mon_merk[$i], $mon_type[$i], $mon_inch[$i], $mon_a_date[$i], $mon_a_prijs[$i]]);
        }
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
$conn = null;
```

Comment: it prints me this on my screen prepare($sql); foreach ($mon_barcode as $i => $barcode) { $insertData = array_merge([$com_id,$barcode],$data); $stmt->execute($insertData); } } catch (PDOException $e) { echo $sql . "
" . $e->getMessage(); } $conn = null; } ?>

Comment: that is like half of the code , so after $conn it starts prepare, probably something wrong while i made my connection

Comment: This code does what you ask, `can this be done in PDO` [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899508/6208408](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899508/6208408)

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your output?

Comment: @YourCommonSense May I ask what I have missed?

Comment: @Cemal uhm it doesnt work for me , but how i see it looks good  idk why it doesnt work for me, i do have connection with my database btw

Comment: @YourCommonSense as the OP told, it's missing some main components, such as db connection etc.

Comment: Which components are you guys aiming for?

Comment: OP, can you check for `?>` right before `prepare($sql);`. If you're going to copy the code above, please ignore the first 4 lines which I assume you have in your code. @YourCommonSense you can try it now.

Comment: Why? You're not being part of a solution my friend. You might not like the way I answered and you can show it by using downvote, not trying to bully your way into it, because you don't like it.

Comment: Uhm yes i already found the problem why it gave that error, I had still die(); somewhere from testing where my errors came from now it results this, you probably can do way more with it ^^ 
error: https://i.imgur.com/jQUleFs.jpg
code: https://i.imgur.com/kWcCHk1.jpg

Comment: Don't care if you're `a friend`. I'm just being respectful. Don't like it, use your middle button to close the tab. **I'm not deleting this. end of discussion. bye.**

Comment: @joepil the code that you have screenshot, doesn't belong to the error. You don't have anything on line 27

Comment: @joepil is any of these `$mon_merk, $mon_type, $mon_inch, $mon_a_date, $mon_a_prijs` an array?

Comment: @Cemal all of them are, this is my form https://i.imgur.com/KySF9TM.jpg

Comment: I do its this line:         $stmt->execute($insertData);

Comment: now I see the problem. Just to be clear, do you need the inputs to be array? from what I can see on your form, they don't need to be.

Comment: uhm its an array because i have a form where you can make multiple input fields with a cap of 5, thats the reason why i use arrays to save them into my database, the upper select menu is my com_ID
https://i.imgur.com/OvnsOtg.jpg

Comment: I've updated the code according to your form. Next time please also mention that those post vars are also array.

Comment: @YourCommonSense and next time you should wait before you say something, atleast Cemal helped me and not you